# div superimposed on other divs

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html code with div tags

```
<div class="left">Proj Name：</div> 
<div class="right">must have a name</div>
<div >Shouldn't this be on a new line?</div>
```

and the classes are defined in a style sheet as

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline
}
.right {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline
}
```

The problem i am having is that there seems to be a super-imposition where any div tag that comes after ignores the existence of the former tags whenever there is an align element involved. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/tea0phnr/2/ for what i am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="left">Proj Name：</div>
<div class="right">must have a name</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div >Shouldn't this be on a new line?</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tea0phnr/3/

Comment: A new element in the markup + class isn't really necessary for his example?

Comment: Beat me by seconds ;)  Though I contained the text in the clear div.  See revision 4.  This is the best practice to follow.  Float and clear are designed to work together.

Comment: It is, and that's what my first fiddle is doing - but you really don't need to create an additional element to accomplish it. He wants the last item on a new line, so that should actually be clearing. If you really wanted to create a special use case element - you could encapsulate it with a pseudo element.

Comment: What if he continues to use float classes else where? Having a clear class is a matter of convenience

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! I agree with Brian, adding a new element is ideal for my case since i have to do this in several other places.

Comment: Then you would put the actual clearing class on the element that doesn't need to float - not create extra markup with the sole purpose of clearing.

Comment: Thanks JamesKorden, Feel free to mark it as correct @atosin if you're happy with the answer or feel free to wait on different approaches. Either way, welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Your floating divs are being pulled out of flow - causing the last div to resume their place in the actual flow. You'd either need to `clear:both;` the last div, or perhaps with a pseudo element. ( div:last-child:after )

```
div:last-child {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzdcu1xw/

or have it `float` + `width: 100%;` as well.

```
div:last-child {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efapLo2d/ in order for it to layout accordingly.